# Bug using Leaflet.awesome-markers plugin and print

Tags: leaflet, javascript, printing, css, icon

I'm using Leaflet awesome marker icons and was almost all right, but when I try print, the icons doesn't show. Why?

I tried:

```
var redMarker = L.AwesomeMarkers.icon({
    icon: 'coffee',
    markerColor: 'red',
    extraClasses: 'PrintOnly'
  });
```

And my CSS:

```
@media print {
    .PrintOnly {
        display:block;
    }
}
```

But it still did not work :(
I am sending the two images to see the error, I have already done everything for the icons to appear, but to no success.

[image: Problem print] and [image: Icons showed]

Answer (score 1):

I founded a solution. I do not think that's the best way to solve this, but it's what I discovered right now and it worked.

In the file `leaflet.awesome-markers.css`, do this:

```
.awesome-marker {
   background: url ('../ images / markers-soft.png') no-repeat 0 0 !important;
   width: 35px;
   height: 46px;
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   display: block;
   text-align: center;
}

.awesome-marker-shadow {
   background: url ('../ images / markers-shadow.png') no-repeat 0 0 !important;
   width: 36px;
   height: 16px;
}

.awesome-marker-icon-blue {
   background-position: -108px 0 !important;
}
```

Just add !important.

Do this for each color of the icon you want to show on the print. If someone has a better solution, I'd love to hear it. Thank you!!